# How can I solve stdarg.h No such file or directory while compiling out-of-tree Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux

I have an out-of-tree Linux kernel module that I need to compile. When I execute "make" in the kernel module directory I am getting:

`"fatal error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory"`

Before starting the build I installed the header file based on my Linux distribution.

`$sudo apt-get install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)`

How can I solve this compilation error? (my distribution is Ubuntu 16.04 with linux-headers-4.15.0-42-generic)

Answer (score 5):

I ran a search of stdarg.h with the "locate" command to see if I can sport the file on the system.

I got:

/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/stdarg.h

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/include/cross-stdarg.h

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/include/stdarg.h

...

It tells me there is at least one stdarg.h provided by the compiler.

I tried to include the path "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/include" in the kernel module Makefile so stdarg.h can be picked up. It did not work (while building, another reference to stdarg.h in the official kernel header was not being resolved).

I finally created a symlink directly under: 
`/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-42-generic/include`

`$sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/include/stdarg.h stdarg.h`

This was just enough to solve the compilation issue.

I am wondering if the kernel headers should come with an implementation of stdarg.h by default (that is the first time I encounter this issue). I have also read that the compiler provide one implementation and most of the time it is better to use the compiler version.

**Updated note:** if the above solution still does not solve the problem:

Before running make again, do a make clean. Do a `ls -la`  in the folder and look for a ".cache.mk" file. If this is still there, remove it and run "make" again. It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

## Issue with VirtualBox kernel modules

I had the same issue with CentOS 9 running in VirtualBox, and the other answers didn't work for me. Apparently the problem is that in more recent kernels, it shouldn't be `<stdarg.h>` but `<linux/stdarg.h>`. With virtualbox guest additions 6.1.34, it correctly checks for kernel with a version of 5.15.0 or more. But my kernel is the 5.14.xx, meaning the include for `stdarg.h` is wrong.

---

## Solving the issue

#### Dependencies

Install all the dependencies for the guest edition

```
gcc make perl kernel-devel kernel-headers bzip2 dkms
```

#### Installation

Run the Guest Addition installation like you would normally. It will fail by saying it is unable to compile the kernel modules. That's expected. It will copy all the file we need to the VM disk.

#### Editing

We now need to edit the erroneous files.

- `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-6.1.34/src/vboxguest-6.1.34/vboxguest/include/iprt/stdarg.h`
- `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-6.1.34/src/vboxguest-6.1.34/vboxsf/include/iprt/stdarg.h`

On line 48 (may change for different versions), it check for a version of Linux and select the correct header depending on the version. We need to replace `if RTLNX_VER_MIN(5,15,0)` with `if RTLNX_VER_MIN(5,14,0)` in both files.

#### Compile the kernel modules

We can now compile the kernel modules, and the error should be gone.

```
sudo rcvboxadd quicksetup all
```

I personally got an error the first time, but then I recompiled without changing anything and it worked.

---

Remember that it's just a workaround, it may not work with different versions.

Answer (score 0):

## If you using Arch Linux with zen-kernel:

```
sudo CPATH=/usr/src/linux-zen/include/linux vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VirtualBox 6.1.0 running archlinux with kernel 6.1.9.
I downloaded **VirtualBoxGuestAdditions_7.2.0.iso** file from https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.2/ link(you may select more appropriate to your VirtualBox version) and assigned as an optical drive to virtualbox machine. After start of the system running **blkid** command on terminal showed the name of CD rom device which was **/dev/sr0**. then I created iso folder on

/mnt  folder

```
mkdir /mnt/iso
```

and mounted cd drive to that folder

```
mount -o loop /dev/sr0 /mnt/iso
```

after I cd'ed to /mnt/iso

```
cd /mnt/iso
```

and manually run VirtualBoxGuestAdditions.run script

```
sh ./VirtualBoxGuestAdditions.run
```

which successfully compiled and istalled required virtualbox guest modules.
Now everytime I update kernel version I redo the same procedure. And it work fine.
It also remove old 6.1.0 guest additons folder.